# Spring Cloud Gateway Custom Filter to Collect Chunks Before Routing

Tags: spring-cloud, spring-cloud-gateway

I am using Spring Cloud Gateway to route requests and I am trying to route a request that is sent by the client via POST with `Transfer-Encoding: chunked` which I want to "collect" all the chunks first before forwarding it as one large payload downstream (essentially removing the chunking).  I would presume there's a way to do this by writing a custom filter (i.e., write an implementation of `GatewayFilterFactory<T>`) to process the http request to wait for all the chunks and create a new body of the combined chunks?  Or is this an unrealistic expectation of what Spring Cloud Gateway is capable of?

Comment: I'm fairly confident it could be done with a custom filter. The modify request body filter reads the whole body

Comment: thanks @spencergibb i kinda sensed that it should work since i implemented a custom transform before similar to [what i described in this gist](https://gist.github.com/dalegaspi/03550807b1c84100dd028fc8e07950ff) and it reads the whole body (same pre- and post- filters)... but I just wanted to confirm if there's any gotchas that I needed to know when using the (custom) modify body filter approach with chunked body.